# Does the Linux kernel implement ad-hoc routing?

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, ad-hoc-network

I know that Linux has support built-in for connecting to ad-hoc networks, but does it implement any ad-hoc routing algorithm? (AODV, DSR, etc.)

I'm searching for an implementation of some routing algorithm but all I can find are old abandoned projects which I'm having trouble building. I can't find any information on whether it's already built-in at all, and don't have access to a linux box that actually has working WiFi, at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes linux kernel has an AODV loadable module present in it and it supports it very well

Kernel AODV

Kernel AODV is a loadable kernel module for Linux.  It implements AODV routing between computers equipped with WLAN devices.

Current version: 2.2.2

Problem with undefined symbols should be fixed.
The entire code base has been renovated. I still needed to add in some comments

http://www.antd.nist.gov/wctg/aodv_kernel/

and linux kernel supports DSR as well.